# Create 1 action but access to 2 Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't know it is the normal behaviour or it is a mistake in my code so I would like to ask this question.

My project using Redux and Redux-Saga.

[image: This is my folder]

I create 1 Action in my Sell component to connect to Money/Reducer. It works well but the thing is in my console log at User/Reducer is running as well.

User/Reducer:

```
const user = (state = initState, action) => {
console.log(action, "action"); //This log is running when I don't do anything with this reducer
switch() {
//switch statement here
}
}
```

Here is my RootReducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import user from './user/Reducer'
import marketPlace from './money/Reducer'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 user,
 marketPlace
})

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, when an `action` being dispatched, the action will flow thru all the reducers, hence you will need the switch case accordingly. Reducer doesn't tide to any specific action, which also means that it gives you the option to update state from different reducers.

Comment: Glad to help Tony